# div: collapse border + change the color of the border on hover + border radius?

Tags: css

this seam easy but i didn't find yet any way to do it. i have 3 divs (but the solution must work for n divs) like on the schema below :

| div 1 || div 2  || div 3  |

ex:

i want normal div like this :

[image]

on hover of a particular div i want ALL border of this div to have another color like this :

[image]

and finally, what i can't do, i want corner like it's show here:

[image]

i want first to collapse all the border. that easy with border-collapse:collapse. but After i want also to change the border color of the full cell on hover (top + left + bottom + right border). that also easy with border: 1px DOUBLE #000. But last (i block on this point) i want also a round corner on the top and bottom left of div 1 and on the top and bottom right of the div 3

it's look like that with border-collapse:collapse their is no way to have round corner ... so need to find another solution

EDIT: I try with the relative position and z-index and it's work a little better ! however i need to know how to move the 2nd div by 1px on the left, the 3th div by 2 pixels on the left, ... and the n div by n-1 pixels on the left?

Comment: Do you have an image that hints us to what you are exactly wanting to achieve on which events? Have you tried using images that change src on hover? How dynamic do you want the number of divs to be?

Comment: i just edit the question with picture if it's can help you ..

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is a little more complicated than you think.

border-collapse is for tables not for all block elements. Of course you can still make it work with display:table/table-cell.
But the hover will still be flawed since the collapsed border will belong to the first element - if you hover the 2nd or 3rd element the left border won't change.

And only then the lack of border-radius for collapsed border comes into play.

I'd say you'll have to go for a different approach. I'd probably go for inline-block (or probably rather with "old-school" floats to avoid whitespace trouble) elements with the borders overlapping by 1px and a change of z-index in the :hover to bring the hovered element to the top and make sure its border is the one displayed.

Comment: "Actually this is a little more complicated than you think" => oooh yes !     "border-collapse is for tables not for all block elements. Of course you can still make it work with display:table/table-cell. But the hover will still be flawed since the collapsed border will belong to the first element - if you hover the 2nd or 3rd element the left border won't change." ==> no with border: 1px double it's work well on all cells

Comment: "with the borders overlapping by 1px" .. i already try, this work good except than on hover i can't change the color of all the border because one is always overlapped by another element :(

Comment: @loki add a positive z-index to the hovered item.

Comment: @loki I actually tried the border double trick... and can't get it to work, the left border won't change on hover (except for the first element).

Comment: no i try the double trick, it's work well. .cont {display:inline-table;border-collapse:collapse;} .div {display:table-cell;box-sizing:border-box;border:1px solid #dedede;} .div:hover {border:1px double #7CCBDE;} work ok !

Comment: but how to use the z-index without position:absolute ? i can't use position:absolute because i  don't know the with of each div :(

Comment: position:relative should work just as well and usually one can get away with that ;-) I got the double trick now, so I actually learned something today :D

Comment: ok, i try the position:relative solution but i have another problem that i describe here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28182242/how-to-move-all-div-by-1px-on-the-left

Answer (score 0):

Not really clear what do you want, but just to try

```css
.one {
    width: 80px;
    height: 40px;
    display: table-cell;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: double 1px black;
}
.one:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
}
.one:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="one"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The border doesn't actually collapse in your example. You need a table element for that which disables the border-radius.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you want?

```css
.container {
  display: table;
}
.container > div {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-top: solid 1px gray;
  border-bottom: solid 1px gray;
  border-left: solid 1px gray;
}
.container > div:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
}
.container > div:last-child {
  border-right: solid 1px gray;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
}
.container > div:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-color: red;
  border-right: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div><div>6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: something like this, but here it's not work :( because here on hover the border not collapse (the red is next to the black border).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that solves the two problems:

- Rounds the outsides. This uses `first-of-type` and `last-of-type` and the `border-radius` property.
- Overlaps the borders.

For the latter, instead of playing with z-indices, what happens is the right border is created and has a color changed. Then, the left-hand border of the next `li` is blanked out. Blanking the next `li` is done by using the adjacent sibling selector (`+`).

Here's a Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JoyGxJ