# How to move all divs by 1px to the left?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I want to do something like this:

```
.cont{position:relative;display:inline-block;}
.cont:nth-child(2) {left:-1px}
.cont:nth-child(3) {left:-2px}
.cont:nth-child(4) {left:-3px}
....
.cont:nth-child(n) {left:-5px}
```

I want to collapse the right div of each cell.

[image]

Something similar to this question :
[collapse border + change the color of the border on hover + border radius?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28180621/div-collapse-border-change-the-color-of-the-border-on-hover-border-radius)

**My HTML:**

```
.main {display:inline-block;border:1px solid #000}

<div class="main">
  <div class="cont">abc<div>
  <div class="cont">def<div>
  <div class="cont">ijk<div>
  <div class="cont">lmo<div>
</div>
```

Also, how to make the main div perfectly wrap its content? The main div has the width of its content before applying the `left:-npx`. With the `-npx`, it leaves an empty space on the right. I want to delete this empty space.

Comment: Apply `margin-left:-1px;` to the `cont` Class

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to add `margin-left:-1px;` to `cont` class.

Answer (score 1):

You want to apply `margin-left: -1px;` to the .cont class.

CSS:

```
.cont {
margin-left:-1px;
}
```